# Replace a hibernate persisted class with its sibling class

Tags: hibernate

I'm working on a project using Hibernate to persist my entities (the full stack includes struts2, spring, jpa & hibernate).

I have two classes `List` and `Pie`, and both inherit from a `Widget` class (using `InheritanceType.JOINED`). I cannot get my head around this situation: I have persisted a `List` entity into the database. But now I want to replace this with a `Pie` entity. How can I do this?

The only thing I can think about is creating another entity, copy the common properties, delete the old one and persist the new one (with a different id), all inside a transaction of course.

Do you know of any other way to do this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No inheritance type was defined... but it is behaving like `InheritanceType.JOINED`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use native queries to modify the stored entity directly.  If you are using a discriminator column, you could modify the value stored in the column for Class A and change it to the value necessary for class B.  You would also need to modify the existing data to match the new class.

I am mentioning this as an alternate approach, but I am not saying that it is necessarily the recommended approach.  Using this technique can cause issues with caching and can affect any live objects that may exist.

The approach you mentioned is one of the cleaner approaches you can use within the JPA space.

**EDIT**

This approach works for all inheritance strategies.  For JOINED and TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance you would need write queries that would migrate the data between tables as well as any discriminator column changes that you may need to set based on the strategy used.

In the long run, this approach could drastically affect the maintainability of your application.  One benefit of the approach you mentioned is that you could leverage reflection to quickly copy over the common fields between the two objects, which simplifies future maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Kris! But using a discriminator column would imply having a massive table with columns for all the properties of each class and I am not sure I want to go that way. Does it have some fantastic benefit or terrible downside vs multiple tables?

Comment: There are three methods used in JPA inheritance: single-table, joined and multi-table.  In the first two you would use a discriminator column, in the third you do not.  The technique I listed works for all (with or without discriminator column), however, it is much more complicated to use native queries to migrate data between multiple tables for the second two approaches.  The approach you use for JPA inheritance storage depends on your data requirements as they each have their pros and cons (search is uses more resources across multiple tables, single table loads more data per row, etc).

Comment: Ok, so basically it's either juggling with jpa or juggling with native queries... I think I'll stick with my first option then... I am planning on having about 6 or 7 classes all inheriting from the same base class (and sometime in the future maybe even more)... But thanks for your comment on maintainability I feel a little bit better about the code I'm about to write!